# Cast IDbSet<Foo> to IDbSet<dynamic>

Tags: c#, .net, dynamic, casting, covariance

I have a utility method that looks something like this

```
 void Apply<T>(IQueryable<T> queryable) where T : class {...}
```

I am doing some reflection to get an instance of `IDbSet<X>` where I *know* that `X` fits those constraints. I'd like to cast that to `IDbSet<dynamic>` so that the compiler will let it through but doing `dbSet as IbSet<dynamic>` returns null. How can I do this?

I realize that I could cast the whole thing to dynamic but there are a few other reasons I would prefer to avoid doing that.

Comment: I don't quite get the use case. You want to cast at call site or inside this method? Or just trying to call this method from some other place that is using reflection?

Comment: @IvanStoev I have a boxed instance of `IQueryable` that I know at runtime conforms to `IQueryable<T>` - I want to pass it into `Apply(..)` but the compiler won't let me.

Comment: If you just want to call `Apply<T>` then you should be able to do `Apply((dynamic)queryable)`.

Comment: @Lee right, but as I mentioned, there are other reasons why I don't want to do that (specifically I want to preserve all the extension method intellisense), and it shouldn't be necessary. I know that it is `IQueryable<dynamic>` - this is *more* specific than `dynamic`.

Comment: @GeorgeMauer But that does exactly what you need. Your method receives the correct T. If you were able to call it with `IQueryable<dynamic>`, then your method T will be `dynamic", which may lead to wrong implementation assumptions.

Comment: If you want more static information then create an `Apply(IQueryable q)` method which makes the dynamic call to the generic method. The problem is that an `IQueryable<T>` is not more specific than an `IQueryable<dynamic>`.

Comment: Fair enough @Lee, and to be honest, that's what I was already doing. But that *is* kind of missing the point of the question. It is in theory possible to preform this cast, but **how**?

Comment: In theory you need existential types to do this which C# does not support e.g. `var eq = (IQueryable<?>)queryable;`